# Canjs created event

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I am trying to detect created event in component. Nothing happens.

```
can.Component.extend({
// todos-list component
// lists todos
tag: "todos-list",
template: can.view("javascript_view/todos-list"),
scope: {
  Todo: Todo,
  todos: TodoList.slice(0),
  todoCreated: function(context, element) {
    // new todo is created
    var Todo = this.Todo;
    new Todo({
      name: can.trim(element.val())
    }).save();
    element.val("");
  }
},
events: {
  "{Todo} created": function(Todo, event, newTodo) {
    console.log("created");
  }
}
});
```

The model is

```
var Todo = can.Model.extend({
// todo model
// fetches things and so on
findAll: function() {
  // get all todos
  return $.Deferred().resolve(todos);
},
findOne: function(params) {
  // get one todo
  return $.Deferred().resolve(todos[(+params.id) - 1]);
},
create: function(attributes) {
  // creates new todo
  var last = todos[todos.length - 1];
  $.extend(attributes, {id: last.id + 1, detail: "", tag: ""});
  todos.push(attributes);
  return $.Deferred().resolve(attributes);
},
update: function(id, attributes) {
  // update one todo
  $.extend(todos[id - 1], attributes);
  return $.Deferred().resolve();
},
destroy: function() {
  // destroy todo
  return $.Deferred().resolve();
}
}, {});
```

Markup is

```
<input type="text" name="todo" placeholder="What needs to be done" can-enter="todoCreated" />
```

Is this correct way of handling created event or is there a better way?
I need list to react when new todo is created.
See [here for code](http://git.io/vrPCTQ)

Comment: Where is the `todos` array coming from?

Comment: Are you rendering a template that contains a `<todo-list>` element?  Are you inserting the results of that template in the page?

Comment: todos has an instance of var TodoList = new Todo.List({}) and yes i am rendering template that contains todo-list

Comment: If you bind to Todo manually, does the event get triggered?  For example `Todo.bind("created", function(){ c.log('event') })`

Comment: If i bind manually it works.

Comment: [Issue #1261](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/1261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug: https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/1261

This is due to CanJS treating the `Todo` constructor as a method because `Todo` is a JS function.

You can get around this by setting Todo on the can.Map instance used as the scope directly as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/c3bfy/147/

The trick is to create a separate view model with the methods you want on the scope:

```
TodoListViewModel = can.Map.extend({
  todoCreated: function(context, element) { ... }
});
```

And to change your scope to return an instance of this view model with `Todo` as a property:

```
scope: function(){
    return new TodoListViewModel({Todo: Todo})
},
```

This forces `Todo` to be treated as a property and not a method.